# Are all objects instances of the (Object) constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop

Are all javascript objects instances of the (Object) constructor?

Is it possible to create objects and at the same time not instances of the (Object) or is this constructor a generic constructor that all objects are instances of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object which has no prototype using the special [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) value.

`null`'s type is `'object'` but it has no prototype either so in some extent it could already qualify as such an *object not `instanceof Object`*.

But we've got to admit that it's a poor candidate, since apart from its type, it's not really an object (e.g we can't add any property to it).

However, as said in the first sentence, we can use it to create an Object which is not `instanceof Object` thanks to [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method :

```js
var o = Object.create(null); // use null has prototype
console.log(o);
console.log('instanceof Object:', o instanceof Object); // false;

o.isAnObject = true;
console.log('can have own properties:', o.isAnObject); // true;
```

Comment: So being an object doesn't necessarily make it an instanceof (Object)?

Comment: @NoOne well no. `instanceof` checks fro the prototype chain. `Object.create(null)` creates an object with `null` as prototype, so `instanceof` will return `false`. But note also that it won't have any of the Object's methods (like `toString()`), so you might not want to do it in real code.